# How to find the number of newlines and word separated by "," in Java?

Tags: java, groovy

My string variable contains a String, each on a different line. How do I find the number of new lines in it, and then each word separated by a `,` delimiter on a particular string line? The variable content is something like below

```
null37,Abhishek,ARS,b,ABC,Development,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net
null38,Abhishek,SAS,c,ABC,Development,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net
null39,Abhishek,DGV,a,ABC,Production,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net
```

Edited:

I tried this

```
String xmlstr="""null37,Abhishek,ARS,b,ABC,Development,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net
null38,Abhishek,SAS,c,ABC,Development,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net
null39,Abhishek,DGV,a,ABC,Production,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net"""

String[] splitStr = xmlstr.split('\n');
for(String str : splitStr)
{
    String splitted = str.split(',');
    println splitted
}
```

I am getting something unknown,

```
[Ljava.lang.String;@148bd3
[Ljava.lang.String;@a4e743
[Ljava.lang.String;@4aeb52
```

Comment: have you try to use csv parser?

Comment: I have no idea about csv parser

Comment: splitted should be String[] (not String) - that was your only mistake - see my answer for more info

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the number of newlines do

```
int newLines = myString.split("\\r?\\n").length;
```

To get each word separated by a comma do

```
String[] words = myString.split(",");
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also use Groovy's `splitEachLine` method.

It works like this:

```
String xmlstr = """null37,Abhishek,ARS,b,ABC,Development,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net
null38,Abhishek,SAS,c,ABC,Development,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net
null39,Abhishek,DGV,a,ABC,Production,2011-05-30 00:00:00.0,abhishek123@cjb.net"""

xmlstr.splitEachLine( /,/ ) { tokens ->
  println "${tokens[1]} : ${tokens[7]}"
}
```

That prints out:

```
Abhishek : abhishek123@cjb.net
Abhishek : abhishek123@cjb.net
Abhishek : abhishek123@cjb.net
```

Answer (score 2):

Your mistake was only that

```
String splitted = str.split(','); // Wrong
```

should have been an **array**:

```
String[] splitted = str.split(','); // Fixed
```

When a Java program prints arrays, the first character is `L` followed by the class, and then the object's memory location.

Here's some Java code that will compile so you can see the problem that scripting languages hide:

```
String[] lines = originalString.split("\\r?\\n")); // Do this only once

int numberOfNewLines = lines.length;
int myLine = 5; // Say

String[] words = lines[myLine];
```

You could easily wrap these idea up in some clean code.

Answer (score 0):

new line char is '\n'.
so you should first split by '\n' .
then split by ',' .

```
String[] splittedByNewLine = originalString.Split('\n');

for(String str : splittedByNewLine )
{
   String[] splittedByComma = str.split(',');
   for(String str : splittedByComma )
   {
       "println str..."
   }       
}
```

Comment: Sorry, the OP tagged the question as `java`. Your code is in C#.

Comment: I converted your code in java and used it, i edited my question can you take a look. Thanks for answering